# Filter data from table by checking field value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have below table structure:

```
refid | model | make | style | imageid   | dealerId   
x23   | X20   | abc  | xyz   | a1b-b2    |   
x23   | X20   | abc  | xyz   | x2m-y3    | 123-456-789
y24   | m30   | jkl  | efg   | y3m-k3    | 
y24   | m30   | jkl  | efg   | k3l-k3    | 333-548-373
```

**Scenario 1:**
if dealerid is empty or null .
**Scenario 2**
if dealerid is not empty or not null with the same data in other column. like above columns.

I have refid in hand (which is foreign key to other table), and I need to select that rows where dealerId value is present.
If dealerId value is not present it should also pick that row and continue to search over other rows. To be very simple, in table both row **can be** present out of which in only one dealerId will be available. 
**Simply I need some kind of if-else condition in sql query which can compare current row data with next row**

Can anyone help me how can I achieve this ?

Comment: please put result set in your question which you want to achieve . it will help others to understand your requirement .

Comment: Please explain clearly ..

Comment: `search for next row in the same manner.` Please define "next"

Comment: @wildplasser **next** means there are multiple rows in the table with duplicate data like above one, but only thing is among two in only one row there would be a dealerId.

Comment: @Ahmed Question is edited now am I able to clear this time ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer, based on how I understand the problem now.

Try this query:

```
select refid, model, make, style, imageid, dealerId
from test t1
where (dealerId is not null and dealerId <>'')
   or not exists (select 1 
                  from test t2
                  where t1.refid = t2.refid
                    and (dealerId is not null and dealerId <>''))
;
```

[`SQLFIddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/10867/2)

Comment: thank you very much.. it worked for me. atleast you have understood my question. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @Aman: `(dealerId is not null and dealerId <>'')` can be replaced with the simple expression `dealerId <>''` - which excludes NULL values automatically.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Ok will try with it, Thanks Erwin :) .

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you need something like that.

```
select refid, model, make, style, imageid,
       coalesce(nullif(dealerId,''), max(dealerId) over (partition by refid))
from test;
```

it will pick `max(dealerId)` for `refid` that has `null` or empty `dealerId`.

[`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/0aaca/11)

Comment: your query looks ok to me... I need to manipulate a little in your query.. I will try with this

Comment: but its returning both rows i.e. row with dealerId and without dealer id. I need to return only one row at a time preferentially that row which have dealerId if second row with dealerId is not present then it should return first row only where dealerId is not present.

Answer (score 0):

Please check query in sqlfiddle 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/0aaca/6/0

Comment: Sorry to say but it didn't helped me. it will only return that rows where dealerId is not null or not empty. but what the requirement is that it should first check if dealerId is not null or empty, pick up that row else pick that row where dealerId is empty or null.. I hope I am able to present my question infront of you...